# removing a hashmap entry and writing it to a file

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to remove a HashMap entry and rewrite it to an existing file but I can't seem to get the HashMap to write to the file with the entry removed although it will locally remove the entry.

```
if(map.containsKey(lastName)){

        map.remove(lastName);
        //Stores all entries from the HashMap in the properties object
        properties.putAll(map);
        //Stores the HashMap in E:\Desktop\Snackdata.properties
        properties.store(new FileOutputStream("E:\\Desktop\\SnackData.properties"), null);
}

else {

        System.out.println("There is no entry under that name.");
}
```

Comment: `although it will locally remove the entry` ... how are you even determining this to be true?

Comment: You need to check if it is removed **from the properties** not from the **map**.

Comment: I ran a print with a .toString() to view the map

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> properties.putAll(map);
> ```

this does **not** remove anything from the properties object.

you also need to call

```
properties.remove(lastName);
```

Comment: @Bman correct ans should be upvoted..don't just mention in comment

Comment: @Chinmay OP needs minimum amount of points to upvote (visibly).